# Handling any datatype as weight in DAG

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a directed acyclic graph implemented in haskell. Currently the weights on the vertices and edges can only be integers, but I want to be able to set the weights as any datatype.

I have a function weight_of_longest_path which looks like this:

```
weight_of_longest_path :: Graph -> Char -> Char -> Int
```

But I would like it to be like this:

```
weight_of_longest_path :: Graph w -> Char -> Char -> (w -> w) -> (w -> w) -> w
```

I would like w to be the weights, and I would also like to pass two functions which can make computations on w (one for vertice weights and one for edge weights).

Because w can be any datatype f and g will need to implement some kind of interface, which can compare and add w. Any ideas on how to implement this?

The algorithm I'm using also need to set the weights for all nodes in "distList" to negative infinity, and this is also going to be a problem since I'm using integers in that list now. How should I work around that problem?

This is my DAG implementation:

```
-- Graph representation

module Badgraph
(Graph(Graph)
, create_graph
, add_vertex
, add_edge
, topological_ordering
, weight_of_longest_path
) where

import Data.Char
import qualified Data.Set as Set
import Data.List

-- Datatype
data Graph = Graph {vertices :: [(Char, Int)],
                      edges :: [(Char, Char, Int)]} deriving Show

-- Creates an empty graph.
create_graph :: Graph  -> Graph
create_graph emptyGraph = Graph [] []

-- Adds a vertex to the graph and returns a char
-- identifier which is the length of the vertice
-- list + 97.
add_vertex :: Graph ->  Int -> Graph
add_vertex (Graph v w) weight = Graph (tuple:v) w
        where tuple = (chr((length v)+97), weight)

-- Adds an edge to the graph.
add_edge :: Graph -> Char -> Char -> Int -> Graph
add_edge (Graph v w) a b weight = Graph v (edge:w)
        where edge = (find_vertice v a, find_vertice v b, weight)

-- Checks to see if the vertex identifier is
-- present in the graph.
find_vertice :: [(Char, Int)] -> Char -> Char
find_vertice [] a = error "Can not find vertice"
find_vertice (x:xs) a =
                if fst x == a then a
                else find_vertice xs a


-- Checks to see if the vertex identifier is
-- present in the graph.
find_vertice :: [(Char, Int)] -> Char -> Char
find_vertice [] a = error "Can not find vertice"
find_vertice (x:xs) a =
                if fst x == a then a
                else find_vertice xs a

-- Gets a topological ordering of the graph.
topological_ordering :: Graph -> [Char]
topological_ordering (Graph v w) =
                let startingNodes = noIncEdges (Graph v w)
                    emptyList = []
                    sorted = sortAlgorithm startingNodes emptyList (Graph v w)
                in sorted

-- Sort algorithm for topological ordering.
sortAlgorithm :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Graph -> [Char]
sortAlgorithm [] sorted _ = sorted
sortAlgorithm (firstVert:remainingVert) sorted (Graph v w) =
                let neighbours = secondNodes $ filter (\(a,b,w) -> a == firstVert) w
                    edges = edgesToRemove firstVert neighbours w
                    newEdges = removeEdges edges w
                    nodes = selectNodes neighbours newEdges
                in  sortAlgorithm (remainingVert ++ nodes) (sorted ++ [firstVert]) (Graph v newEdges)

weight_of_longest_path :: Graph -> Char -> Char -> Int
weight_of_longest_path  (Graph v w) startVert endVert =
                        let topSort = dropWhile (/= startVert) $ topological_ordering (Graph v w)
                            finalList = getFinalList (Graph v w) topSort (makeDistList v topSort startVert)
                        in  getVerticeWeight endVert finalList

getFinalList :: Graph -> [Char] -> [(Char, Int)] -> [(Char, Int)]
getFinalList _  [] finalList  = finalList
getFinalList (Graph v w) (firstVert:rest) distList =
            let neighbours = findNeighbours firstVert w
                finalList = updateList firstVert neighbours distList (Graph v w)
            in  getFinalList (Graph v w) rest finalList

updateList :: Char -> [Char] -> [(Char, Int)] -> Graph -> [(Char, Int)]
updateList _ [] updatedList _  = updatedList
updateList firstVert (neighbour:rest) distList (Graph vertices weights) =
           let edgeWeight = getEdgeWeight firstVert neighbour weights
               verticeWeight = getVerticeWeight neighbour vertices
               newDist = calcDist firstVert neighbour verticeWeight edgeWeight distList
               updatedList = replace distList neighbour newDist
           in  updateList firstVert rest updatedList (Graph vertices weights)

calcDist :: Char -> Char -> Int -> Int -> [(Char, Int)] -> Int
calcDist firstVert neighbour verticeWeight edgeWeight distList =
         if compareTo (getVerticeWeight neighbour distList) ((getVerticeWeight firstVert distList) + edgeWeight)
         then (getVerticeWeight firstVert distList) + edgeWeight + verticeWeight
         else getVerticeWeight neighbour distList

compareTo :: Int -> Int -> Bool
compareTo val1 val2 =
          if val1 < val2
          then True
          else False

replace :: [(Char, Int)] -> Char -> Int -> [(Char, Int)]
replace distList vertice value = map (\p@(f, _) -> if f == vertice then (vertice, value) else p) distList

makeDistList :: [(Char, Int)] -> [Char] -> Char -> [(Char, Int)]
makeDistList vertices topSort startVert = distList
             where distList = zip topSort $ (snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == startVert) vertices):(repeat (-999))

findNeighbours :: Char -> [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [Char]
findNeighbours vert edges = secondNodes $ filter (\(a,b,w) -> a == vert) edges

getVerticeWeight :: Char -> [(Char, Int)] -> Int
getVerticeWeight vert vertList = snd $ head $ filter (\(a,b) -> a == vert) vertList

getEdgeWeight :: Char -> Char -> [(Char, Char, Int)] -> Int
getEdgeWeight vert1 vert2 edges = selectThird $ head $ filter (\(a,b,w) -> a == vert1 && b == vert2) edges

-- Checks which vertices has no incoming edges.
noIncEdges :: Graph -> [Char]
noIncEdges (Graph v w) =
        let set1 = Set.fromList $ firstNodes w
            set2 = Set.fromList $ secondNodes w
            startNodes = Set.toList $ Set.difference set1 set2
        in  startNodes

-- Checks which edges to remove
edgesToRemove :: Char -> [Char] -> [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [(Char, Char, Int)]
edgesToRemove _ [] _ = []
edgesToRemove firstVert (firstNbr:neighbours) edges =
            filter (\(a,b,w) -> (a == firstVert && b == firstNbr)) edges ++
            edgesToRemove firstVert neighbours edges

-- Removes edges
removeEdges :: [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [(Char, Char, Int)]
removeEdges edgesToRemove edges =
                let set1 = Set.fromList edgesToRemove
                    set2 = Set.fromList edges
                    newEdges = Set.toList $ Set.difference set2 set1
                in  newEdges

-- Selects vertices depending on
selectNodes :: [Char] -> [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [Char]
selectNodes  [] _ = []
selectNodes  (firstNbr:neighbours) edges =
             if filter (\(a,b,w) -> b == firstNbr) edges == []
             then firstNbr:selectNodes neighbours edges
             else selectNodes neighbours edges

selectFirst :: (Char, Char, Int) -> Char
selectFirst (a, _, _) = a

selectSecond :: (Char, Char, Int) -> Char
selectSecond (_, a, _) = a


selectThird :: (Char, Char, Int) -> Int
selectThird (_, _, w) = w

firstNodes :: [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [Char]
firstNodes [] = []
firstNodes (x:xs) = selectFirst x:firstNodes xs

secondNodes :: [(Char, Char, Int)] -> [Char]
secondNodes [] = []
secondNodes (x:xs) = selectSecond x:secondNodes xs
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Give `Graph` a type parameter:

```
data Graph a = Graph {
    vertices :: [(Char, a)],
    edges :: [(Char, Char, a)]
}
```

However, while your at it, it could be worthwhile to think about whether you really want to put those tuples everywhere or use type synonyms:

```
type Vertex a = (Char, a)
type Edge a   = (Char, Char, a)

data Graph a = Graph {
  getVertices :: [Vertex a],
  getEdges    :: [Edge a]
} deriving (Show, Eq, Read)

emptyGraph :: Graph a
emptyGraph = Graph [] []

addVertex :: Graph a -> a -> Graph a
addVertex (Graph vs es) v = Graph ((chr(length vs+97), v):vs) es

addEdge :: Graph a -> Edge a -> Graph a
addEdge (Graph vs es) e = Graph vs (e:es)

findVertex :: (Eq a) => Graph a -> Vertex a -> Maybe (Vertex a)
findVertex g v = find (==v) . getVertices $ g

-- ...
```

Also, think about whether you *really* want `Char` as vertex id. Usually you take the natural numbers:

```
type VertexId = Int -- or Integer
type Vertex a = (VertexId, a)
type Edge a   = (VertexId, VertexId, a)

data Graph a = Graph {
  getVertices :: [Vertex a],
  getEdges    :: [Edge a]
} deriving (Show, Eq, Read)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely use type synonyms. Also didn't know about the find function, neat! 

But I'm still confused on what to do with all the values in distList when I'm computing longest path. Would it be possible do insert some kind of null value instead of -999?

Comment: @user1900750 If you need a data type that can be `null` or a valid value, you should be using the `Maybe a = Nothing | Just a` type.  It encodes the notion of `null` at the type system level, forcing you to explicitly handle it at every point it is used, and `Data.Maybe` contains useful function for working with the type.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've never used Maybe datatypes before though (just started with haskell). Trying to remake the list like this: zip topSort (repeat Graph2.Nothing) but this error occurs  "Couldn't match expected type w with actual type Graph2.Maybe w0". How do I avoid this?

Comment: @user1900750 It's hard to tell from this error fragment, but it looks like you haven't change a type signature somewhere or re-written a function to handle the `Maybe w` type signature.  You also should use the built-in `Maybe` definition, it has some really handy instances like `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad` defined already.  If you could post the problematic code as a pastebin/gist/etc I could take a look at it.

Comment: You could make the indeces a parameter too, `data Graph i a = Graph {vertices :: [Vertex i a], edges :: [Edge i a]}`.

Comment: @AndrewC: True, if you really want to make it general, yes. However, in this case, `i` would need to be an instance of `Enum`, such that one could use `succ` or `toEnum 1`.